# how to get other own file in googledrive with apiclient in python?

Tags: python

i tried get method but response is not found file. 
when i get other own file.
when i get file info my own file. it is possible.
how to access other own file...
this is my code
file_id value replace [google_id] cause security

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
]
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

file_id = '[google_id]'
file = service.files().get(
    fileId=file_id, supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()
new_title = '[bob]'
file['title'] = new_title
new_filename = '[bob].mp4'
new_revision = True
updated_file = service.files().update(
    fileId=file_id,
    body=file,
    newRevision=new_revision,
    media_body=('__init__.py'), supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()
print(repr(updated_file))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 When a file owner tries to access something that is not mine but i have authroization, it says that the file can not be found.
What should I do?

Comment: I am trying to get file information using the get function with googleclient python api, but i am not owner that file.

Comment: just by sharing and i receive authorization that files.

Comment: error message "returned "File not found:"

Comment: you probably do not have permission to access that file

Comment: i solved that i was miss delete credentials file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved that i was miss delete credentials file.
so i do not have permission to access that file. thanks.